# How to enable existing job in Jenkins using job DSL or other means?

Tags: jenkins

I use Jenkins job DSL script to create other jobs. Now I want to have a separate script that will enable/disable the jobs that I created by the DSL script.

Here is my enable/disable script:

```
job("cronjob/${JOB_TYPE}_${ENVRIONMENT}_CRONJOB") {
  if ( ACTION == "enable" ) {
    disabled(false)
  } else if ( ACTION == "disable" ) {
    disabled(true)
  }
}
```

It does enable/disable the job. But it also empties the job which has the SCM, schedule and parameters setup.

How do I enable/disable an existing job in Jenkins w/o losing the job? Not manually!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the followig script to do this.

```
def jobToDisable = "Sample"
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each { jobitem ->
            def jobName = jobitem.name
            def jobInfo = Jenkins.instance.getItem(jobName)
        
            if(jobName.equals(jobToDisable)) {
                jobInfo.setDisabled(true) // false to enable
            }   
   }
```

Full pipeline

```
node {
    stage('Stage one') {
       script {
           disableJob("folder1/Sample3")
       }
    }

    stage('Final Step') {
        echo "Result"
    }
}


def disableJob(name) {
    def jobToDisable = name
    Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each { jobitem ->
                def jobName = jobitem.getFullName()
                def jobInfo = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName)

                if(jobName.equals(jobToDisable)) {
                    println("Disabling Job!!")
                    jobInfo.setDisabled(true)
                }   
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Tried to run it, and got the error: ```Processing provided DSL script
ERROR: (script, line 2) No such property: Jenkins for class: script
Finished: FAILURE```.  not sure what else is missing...

Comment: @PhilipShangguan You can test the script in Jenkins Script Console as well. I updated the answer with a full pipeline.

Comment: thanks for new code. I tested it again and it finished successfully, but it did not enable or disable the job. The only change I did was in Stage one: ```disableJob("cronjob/inflate_apollo_environment_CRONJOB" as String)```. The job is inside a folder ```cronjob```.

Comment: @PhilipShangguan updated the code to handle Jobs within folders.

Comment: the getFullName worked. Thanks a lot!